# Error invoking command to install a Msi through Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, wmic

I am trying to use PowerShell's Invoke-Command but I am encountering an error that I have no idea of what it is!

Would be great to have some help on this. I am sure that it must be something really simple..

```
invoke-command  -scriptblock{ $executable = "wmic"; & "$executable product call install true","-computername name" ,'path to the msi' }
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Paul do you have any idea of what it might be?

Comment: Downvoted for failing to include the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try using msiexec:

```
$scriptblock = {Start-Process msiexec.exe -Argumentlist "/i $PathToMSI","/qn"}
invoke-command  -scriptblock $scriptblock -computername $name
```

I´m not sure if you even can install msi´s via wmi, never seen it before. Other than that you mixed up the syntax of your invoke-command a bit ;)

Comment: what syntax mix-ups did I do?